# ACF value display in checkout and order summary

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, hook-woocommerce

I need your assistance. I wrote the following code

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'show_vin', 30 );

function show_vin() {
   global $product;
   $arithmos_plaisiou = get_field( "arithmos_plaisiou" );
   if ( $product && has_term( 'antallaktika', 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
?> 
        <div class="show_ask_vin">
            <label id="vin_label" for="vin_input">*Αριθμός πλαισίου οχήματος:</label>
            <input type="text" id="vin_input" name="vin_input" value="<?php echo esc_attr($arithmos_plaisiou); ?>">
        </div>
    <script>
        jQuery(function($) {
            // Attach a submit event handler to the add-to-cart form
            $('form.cart').submit(function() {
                // Get the value of the VIN input field and trim any leading or trailing whitespace
                var vinValue = $('#vin_input').val().trim();
                
                // Check if the VIN input length is exactly 17 characters
                if (vinValue.length !== 17) {
                    // If it's not 17 characters, prevent the form submission and display an error message
                    alert('Παρακαλώ εισάγετε τον αριθμό πλαισίου 17 ψηφίων! ');
                    return false; // Prevent form submission
                }
                // Add the VIN value to the cart item data
                $('input[name="vin_input"]').val(vinValue);
                
                // If the VIN input length is 17 characters, allow the form submission
                return true;
            });
        
        });
        </script>
        <?php
}}
```

to add an ACF to single product page to ask for VIN number of a car when product meets a certain category. I want to pass the value of the ACF field to woocommerce order summary.
I tried some solution i found but none of them worked.

Tried the following snippets

```
// Save VIN value to cart item data
add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'save_vin_to_cart', 10, 2);
function save_vin_to_cart($cart_item_data, $product_id) {
    if (isset($_POST['vin_input'])) {
        $cart_item_data['vin_input'] = sanitize_text_field($_POST['vin_input']);
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}

// Display VIN value in cart
add_filter('woocommerce_get_item_data', 'display_vin_in_cart', 10, 2);
function display_vin_in_cart($item_data, $cart_item) {
    if (!empty($cart_item['vin_input'])) {
        $item_data[] = array(
            'key'   => 'VIN',
            'value' => $cart_item['vin_input']
        );
    }
    return $item_data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need JavaScript, instead use WooCommerce product field validation… Now your field need to be inside the add to cart form, allowing the validation and allowing to add this inputted field value as custom cart item data:

```php
// Display the field
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'show_vin', 30 );
function show_vin() {
    global $product;

    $field_value = get_field('arithmos_plaisiou', $product->get_id());

    if ( !empty($field_value) && has_term( 'antallaktika', 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
        echo '<div class="show_ask_vin">
            <label id="vin_label" for="vin_input">'.__('*Αριθμός πλαισίου οχήματος:').'</label>
            <input type="text" id="vin_input" name="vin_input" value="'.esc_attr($field_value).'">
        </div>';
    }
}

// Validate the field
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'validate_vin' );
function validate_vin( $passed ) {
    if ( isset($_POST['vin_input']) ) {
        if ( empty($_POST['vin_input']) ) {
            wc_add_notice( __('Το πεδίο "Αριθμός πλαισίου οχήματος" είναι υποχρεωτικό.', 'woocommerce'), "error" );
            $passed = false;
        } elseif ( strlen( sanitize_text_field($_POST['vin_input']) ) !== 17 ) {
            wc_add_notice( __('Παρακαλώ εισάγετε τον αριθμό πλαισίου 17 ψηφίων!', 'woocommerce'), "error" );
            $passed = false;
        }
    }
    return $passed;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.